# How much should we archive for reproducible builds?

Tags: version-control, repository, build-system, package-managers

A few alternative twists on the question title to contextualize further:

- What to archive of the "sources" for a given software build?
- Should I include all transitive packages in my repository?
- Is it OK to rely on the package manager to be able to reproduce a build at all?
- Should I archive a ZIP file of my git repo release tag?
- Should we archive the build tools?

---

Context:

- Building an application that will be installed on multiple users' machines / devices.
- The code is parts C# and parts C++, all compiled with MS Visual Studio.
- Reproducible build means, *for us*: Given an old SCC-release-tag, you can build these sources into working binaries that use exactly the same versions of all dependencies as the original build and produce a working application binary set.

  - In the context of our CI pipeline within our infrastructure this is already guaranteed. (We lock in *all* 3rd party lib versions, and all dependency packages are fetched from our private server.
- The produced binaries need not be 100% identical -- indeed, in our current system, they would get a new automated build number in their version.

---

OK, so here's the problem:

Obviously, all of **our source code** lives in source control. This is NOT enough to build the software however.

When you want to create a binary build of the application, you need:

- Install Visual Studio in the correct version (we automate this via Chocolatey).
- (a) Check out the correct SCC "release tag".
- Run "the build script":

  - (b.1) Run a nuget restore against our internal package server
  - (b.2) Fetch 3rd party sources that are not checked in the primary repo (think vcpckg or something similar)
  - (c) Build the actual software (call msbuild in our case)
  - (d) Package the created application binaries into something that can be passed downstream

Note: Normally all of the above, and more, is run in the automated CI System (using Jenkins here).

Some here think we should create and archive a "ZIP file" before step (c) so that we have a base for a "reproducible build" and *can reproduce a given build on any dev machine without relying on our source code server and/or our package mgmt server* -- and more specifically, *without relying on the scripted part(s)* of steps (b.#) as these have to get all the *settings for the infrastructure* correct (server names etc.) which could change over time.

Some here think that's a waste of time and space, as the whole build system is critical infra anyway, so having something that "works without it" doesn't make sense.

Is there some accepted norm with regard to this?

Comment: The answer depends on what problem you're trying to solve. Why are reproducible builds important to you?

Comment: Most package managers support *lockfiles*, including Nuget. So the first thing to do is to enable it.

Comment: @curiousdannii - we already use a form of locking in the dependencies. A build is 100% reproducible, given our infrastructure is online.

Comment: How reproducible? Could be anywhere from just wanting to get a warning if something might have changed to needing bit-for-bit identical outputs at any arbitrary point in the future.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks, I should clarify that.

Comment: What are your threats? If you're worried about packages disappearing from the Internet, you'll need your build tools and all of your dependencies archived. If you also worried about being able to run your software, you may also need the target OS. But maybe it's better to archive builds/releases (and correlate each one to source control) rather than necessarily being able to recreate each built. There are lots of options here.